# Trying to get Bootsrap pagination to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap's pagination

I got the HTML code on official Bootstrap's page, but I need the content to change when I go to the next page. Does anyone know how can I get it working?

```html
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="https://robohash.org/88.130.49.243.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Card Text.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="customPagination flexCenter mt-2">
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link bg-transparent" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
          <span aria-hidden="true"><</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link bg-transparent" href="#" aria-label="Next">
          <span aria-hidden="true">></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The bootstrap pagination UI is literally just the buttons. You need to write the logic to actually retrieve and display the data in pages yourself.

Comment: Your requirement is similar to bootstrap carousel. Please refer this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) Just replace the ul>li pagination dots with numbers

Comment: issue is all the page numbers have same content to show which is image in your case. check the proper way of doing pagination in bootstrap is this. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for - [bootstrap carousel pagination](https://codepen.io/hmache/pen/oLrWRJ)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Bootstrap carousel with number indicator</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators --> 
  <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators-numbers">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-indicators-numbers {
    li {
      text-indent: 0;
      margin: 0 2px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 100%;
      line-height: 30px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #999;
      transition: all 0.25s ease;
      &.active, &:hover {
        margin: 0 2px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #337ab7;        
      }
    }
}
```